# What is the purpose of double curly braces in React's JSX syntax?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

From the [react.js tutorial](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) we see this usage of double curly braces:

```
<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: rawMarkup }} />
```

And then in [the second tutorial, "Thinking in react"](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html):

```
 <span style={{ color: 'red' }}>
     {this.props.product.name}
 </span>;
```

However, the [React JSX documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) doesn't describe or mention double curly braces.  What is this syntax (double curlies) for? And is there another way to express the same thing in jsx or is this just an omission from the documentation?

Comment: From documentation `The exterior set of curly braces are letting JSX know you want a JS expression. The interior set of curly braces represent a JavaScript object, meaning you’re passing in a object to the style attribute.`

Answer (score 167, accepted):

It's just an object literal inlined in the prop value. It's the same as

```
var obj = {__html: rawMarkup};

<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={obj} />
```

Comment: @BenAlpert I'd be happy to when I get a moment. Weirdly, I actually enjoy editing documentation (was an editor of a legal journal in a previous incarnation) and there may be a few other improvements to be had there.  PS, still living in Boulder? Lets grab coffee or lunch sometime... it would be good to know someone with the inside scoop on React since we're just starting a big project with it.

Comment: @BenRoberts Great, thank you! Unfortunately I'm out in California these days but feel free to drop by the #reactjs IRC room on freenode and I'd be happy to answer questions.

Comment: @BenAlpert do you happen to know what the thinking was behind making it `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={__html: rawMarkup}` instead of `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={rawMarkup}`? Is it because the object `{__html: rawMarkup}` is mutable and a string isn't?

Comment: @Brian: See https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2256#issuecomment-63031960 (and https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/6f44f6049edfd7a66448ac50cd4415f6c26fd4b5/docs/tips/19--dangerouslySetInnerHTML.md).

Answer (score 106):

Curly braces has got 2 usage here:-

1. { .. } evaluates to an expression in JSX.
2. { key: value } implies a javascript object.

Let see a simple example.

`<Image source={pic} style={{width: 193}}/>`

If you observe `pic` is surrounded by braces. That's the JSX way of embedding variable. `pic` can be any Javascript expression/variable/object.
You can also do something like { 2+3 } and it will evaluate to { 5 }

Let's dissect style here.
`{width: 193}` is a Javascript object.
And to embed this object in JSX you need curly braces, hence, `{ {width: 193} }`

> Note: To embed any kind of Javascript expression/variable/object in JSX you need curly braces.

Comment: @RohitMandiwal Thank you Sir. I know it's a little bit confusing when you got one curly brace inside other.

Comment: What a great explanation of double curly braces in React!
Thank you very much!
I will vote this answer as the most practical explanation.

Answer (score 26):

The syntax of `{{color: 'red'}}` is used in the `style` tag because according to the [React doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style), the `style` attribute accepts a ***JavaScript object*** with camelCased properties rather than a ***CSS string***.

```
<span style={{color: 'red'}}>
    {this.props.product.name}
</span>;
```

Answer (score 9):

React uses JSX, In JSX for evaluation of any variable, state object , expression etc has to be enclosed in {}.

While giving inline styles in JSX, it has to be specified as an object so it has to be inside curly braces again. {}.

This is the reason there are two pairs of curly braces

Comment: What does it mean to evaluate a Javascript object? I get evaluating a variable, b/c I have to get the actual value, but if I give an actual object, what's left to be evaluated?

Comment: @Elliptica Not in touch with it right now but I guess it can be ToString conversion of object.

Answer (score 4):

My interpretation of the double curly brackets is that the style object only accepts a JavaScript object, so the object has to be inside of single curly brackets.

```
style={jsObj}
```

The object for style artifacts is of key:value pairs (dictionary versus an array) and that object is expressed as, for example, `{color:'#ffffff'}`.

So you've got:

```
style = { jsObj }
```

and

```
jsObj = {color:'#ffffff'}
```

Just like in algebra, when you substitute, it stands that:

```
style = { {color:'#ffffff'} }
```

Answer (score 3):

this means instead of declaring a style variable that is set to an object of the intended style properties you can instead just set the style properties in an object... this is usually a best practice when the styles you want to add are few however for an element that needs more style it is cleaner to declare a style variable

for instance for an element with fewer style properties do this

```
<span style={{color: 'red'}}>
  {this.props.product.name}
</span>
```

for HTML element with more style properties do this

```
const spanStyle = {
   backgroundColor: 'red',
   color: 'grey',
   margin: '-25px'
}
```

then you call it with jsx syntax

```
<span style={spanStyle}>
  {this.props.product.name}
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a JSX syntax notation, normal HTML accepts inline styles with strings like `style="color:red"`, but JSX syntax don't accept inline styles in form of string. We have to pass them as Objects dynamically and only way to embed JavaScript objects in JSX is to use {} notation, which gives us syntax like `style={{color:'red'}}`

Answer (score 0):

Two steps:

jsObj = {color:'#ffffff'} // First set of braces

style = { jsObj } // Second set of braces

Or one step:

style = { {color:'#ffffff'} } // First & second sets of braces together

As Lama said: "Isn't that easy"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33291174)

Answer (score 0):

From https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.70/intro-react :

Notice the double curly braces {{ }} surrounding style‘s width and height. In JSX, JavaScript values are referenced with {}. This is handy if you are passing something other than a string as props, like an array or number: <Cat food={["fish", "kibble"]} age={2} />. However, JS objects are also denoted with curly braces: {width: 200, height: 200}. Therefore, to pass a JS object in JSX, you must wrap the object in another pair of curly braces: {{width: 200, height: 200}}

Answer (score -1):

Two sets of curly braces is because we want to provide an object there like so:

```
function App() {
  return <input style={{ border: '3px solid red' }} />
}

root.render(<App />);
```

Answer (score -2):

I try to tell it in simple words to be understandable for everyone. The below code:

`<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: rawMarkup}} />`

is equal to

```
<span 
     dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {__html: rawMarkup} } 
/>
```

So, simply we should use React expression if we're going to assign a **literal object** to a property.

For some people who are mainly moving from AngularJs to ReactJs, it is probably a part of confusion with the AngularJs' expression binding operator **{{ }}**. So, try to look at it differently in ReactJs.

Comment: Your two code fragments seem to be exactly the same except for formatting.

Comment: @jcollum - that's exactly his point.  The double brace "operator" isn't an operator which is what he was showing.  It's just so common in html templating engines that it looks weird in react.

Comment: I still don't get it

Comment: @AndrewLam - Just edited it. Can you understand it now?