# Double curly braces in React expression

Tags: reactjs

I came across the following code from the React documentation:

```
import {ThemeContext} from './theme-context';

class ThemedButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let props = this.props;
    let theme = this.context;
    return (
      <button
        {...props}
        style={{backgroundColor: theme.background}}
      />
    );
  }
}
ThemedButton.contextType = ThemeContext;

export default ThemedButton;
```

Why does style have double curly braces instead of just one?:

```
style={{backgroundColor: theme.background}}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of double curly braces in React's JSX syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671582/what-is-the-purpose-of-double-curly-braces-in-reacts-jsx-syntax)

Comment: Because you're creating an `React.CSSProperties` object with fields `backgroundColor`..., or any other valid field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inner curly braces are an object, no different from:

```js
const myStyles = {backgroundColor: theme.background};
```

and then:

```js
<button style={myStyles} />
```

The outer curly braces wrap an **expression**, which might be a variable, an object, a function, or anything that can resolve to a value.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you are passing a prop to react component.

`<Component value={"somevalue"} />` Here the value is string but you still need curly braces as the format.
const a = {a: 1}
`<Component value={a} />` Here a is object if you embed the object `<Component value={{a: 1}} />`

Same way style is an object need to be passed to the React element.

you can do also

`const style = {
myClass: {color: "red"}
}
<div style={style.myClass} />`