# Unable to pass state value through react jsx. Getting error - Unexpected token : 'this'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-state-management, react-state

The following code initializes `state` keys as `NULL` and assigns them certain values on mounting of components. (All this is working fine)

The problem is in accessing these state values in the `render` function.
In `Map` Component, `initialCenter` attribute takes an object as value. This where I am passing the state value and getting the following error.

Failed to compile
./src/components/Mapcontainer.js
Line 32:21:  Parsing error: Unexpected keyword 'this'

```
export class MapContainer extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      lat: null,
      lng: null,
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
      this.setState({
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude,
      });
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Map
        google={this.props.google}
        zoom={14}
        style={mapStyles}
        initialCenter={{
          lat: {this.state.lat},
          lng: {this.state.lng},
        }}
      >
      <Marker />
      </Map>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
initialCenter={{
   lat: {this.state.lat},
   lng: {this.state.lng},
}}
```

should be

```
initialCenter={this.state}
```

or

```
initialCenter={{
   lat: this.state.lat,
   lng: this.state.lng
}}
```

because you'll have nested objects in the prior case. And `lat: {this.state.lat}` will cause a syntax error because `{this.state.lat}` will result in an object without a key.

Answer (score 1):

No need of wrapping the javascript code again in the curly braces for `lat: {this.state.lat}` or `lng: {this.state.lng}`. Just do this

```
<Map
        google={this.props.google}
        zoom={14}
        style={mapStyles}
        initialCenter={{    // one for expression evaluation and one for object literal
          lat: this.state.lat,
          lng: this.state.lng,
        }}
      >
```

For more explaination, see following stackoverflow thread.

[what-is-the-purpose-of-double-curly-braces-in-reacts-jsx-syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671582/what-is-the-purpose-of-double-curly-braces-in-reacts-jsx-syntax).